# Newly Open Apps Take Priority Over the App I'm Working On

Tags: window, gnome-shell

So I multi-task a lot and am fairly new to Linux. I've been using Linux for a couple of months on GS Voyager and now just on Ubuntu 17.10.

I'll have apps running in the background and maybe writing out a document or searching the web. If a new window pane (if I'm using the correct terms for Linux xD) then it'll force me out of my reddit scrolling or my libreDocument.

Is there a way to configure this so that new apps don't take priority?

Comment: Strange! The default behaviour of GNOME shell (Ubuntu 17.10 default) is complete opposite. New windows open in background and you just get a notification at the top saying "*the new window* is ready", like this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/screenshots/screenshot_1005_UjrkyiW.png Are you using a different flavour (Xubuntu/Lubuntu/Ubuntu MATE etc.)?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 17.10. I downloaded the iso off their website. It's definitely GNOME even though it still looks a bit like unity.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XF5Vs --> for reference. I'm almost positive this is GNOME 3

Comment: Yes, it looks like GNOME 3 no doubt. Could you [edit] your question and add the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`?

Comment: By output do you mean tags for my question? I've been trying to learn as i go this is my first post on here

Comment: No, I meant open Terminal in your computer, run the command `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` and copy the output and paste it here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dFxVP